# wifi6 TWT(target wake time)

Tags: android, linux-kernel, wpa-supplicant

What is the interface for calling the TWTdriver at the Android framework or supplicant layer?

struct cfg80211_ops ?
Now when I debug TWT, I directly operate the driver layer. How to realize the automatic power management of the upper layer? I want to get an upper layer interface.